Modify the Reference Level gtsummary
Am trying to replace the _ in the regression table in gtsummary with Ref. My old code does not work as it used to be. I will appreciate assistance....
library(gtsummary)
mod1 <- glm(response ~ trt + age + grade, trial, family = binomial)

t1 <- tbl_regression(mod1, exponentiate = TRUE) 
 
# This code would do the trick but does not currently does not. Using `gtsummary_2.0.3`

t1 |>  
modify_table_styling(
  rows = reference_row %in% TRUE,
  missing_symbol = "Ref"
)


It looks like you need to specify the columns you want to apply this change to using the modify_table_styling(columns) argument. Example below!
library(gtsummary)
mod1 <- glm(response ~ trt + age + grade, trial, family = binomial)

t1 <- tbl_regression(mod1, exponentiate = TRUE) 

# This code would do the trick but does not currently does not. Using `gtsummary_2.0.3`

t1 |>  
  modify_table_styling(
    columns = c(estimate, conf.low),
    rows = reference_row %in% TRUE,
    missing_symbol = "Ref"
  ) |> 
  bold_labels() |> 
  as_kable() # convert to kable to display on SO




Characteristic
OR
95% CI
p-value




Chemotherapy Treatment





Drug A
Ref
Ref



Drug B
1.13
0.60, 2.13
0.7


Age
1.02
1.00, 1.04
0.10


Grade





I
Ref
Ref



II
0.85
0.39, 1.85
0.7


III
1.01
0.47, 2.15
>0.9



Created on 2024-11-09 with reprex v2.1.1
